# Rewritten URL being logged by Google as multiple URL's

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have rewritten url to shorten using .htaccess

```
Original url: `domain.com/content.php?language=en&section=1&english_page_id=5&shortname=page-name`
New url: `domain.com/en/1/5/page-name`
```

I am using the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /content.php?language=$1&section=$2&english_page_id=$3&shortname=$4 [L]
```

I have noticed from Google Web Tools that the url is being logged under various url's and therefore appearing as duplicated content. Investigating this it would appear that my url rewrite is also allowing a blank entry after the final slash.

Duplicated URL's

```
domain.com/en/14/5/
domain.com/en/14/5/anything
domain.com/en/14/5/ anything
domain.com/en/14/5/any thing
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the canonical URL - ie the authoritative url for the page content. This is basically a `<link>` tag in `<head>` with the address you want Google to log instead of the actual one.

See http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.gr/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

In your provided example, you could add the tag

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain.com/en/1/5/page-name" />
```

in the `<head>` of your page, and Google would treat all links with this content as the same page.

Comment: Thanks hexblot. Can I populate this tag dynamically as well using mysql entries?

Comment: Don't worry just answered it myself :o)

Comment: So added the tag but the problem is continuing and escalating. I have asked google to recrawl but still no joy. Any other ideas?

Comment: assuming that both the pages ( ie http://example.com/url1 and /url2 ) have the same canonical, they will be considered as one by Google. Check manually (view the source) that they get generated properly as an anonymous user, and wait - it can take a bit for Google to pick the changes up.